# ASP.net: distinguish between internal ASP exceptions and real exceptions

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging, exception

We have a asp.net application and want to implement logging.
The first idea was to use the Application_Error method in the global.asax file.

The problem is that ASP.NET very often seem to throw exceptions internally that are not caused by the application and which seem not to interfer with the users normal workflow.
For example we often get HTTPExceptions, UnauthorizedAccessExceptions and others caught in this method, although there is no real error in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way. Most Exceptions occur because the client requests files which are not available on the server ("favicon..").

Answer (score 0):

For logging purpose I think the MS Entreprise Library with the logging application blog will do what you want.. (wrapping inner exception) Also if you want catch specific exception you can create your own Exception class like BusinessLogicException .. and check if the throw exception is this exception and after loggin it .. for the other continue .. with normal execution 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=PandP.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)

Comment: We are already using log4net. The problem is, we want not only catch/log certain exceptions but instead all, like IndexOutOfRange and NullReference. But how can we distinguish them from internal asp.net errors?